# qqPloting subset of data R

Tags: r, plot, subset

I have R data that looks like this.

```
Year    Total
2005    238.79
2005    165.46
2005    196.07
2005    135.28
2005    180.30
2005    237.95
2005    714.74
2005    828.19
2005    516.19
2005    279.76
2005    281.88
2005    338.68
```

The left most column Year goes from 2005 to 2009. I want to do a qqPlot of the Total using only the files that have 2005 in the year column. how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `subset()`, which might seem more natural:

```
tmp <- subset(dat, subset = Year == 2005, select = Total)
qqnorm(tmp)
qqline(tmp)
```

Do note that `subset()` is not recommended for use in programming as the sugar that makes it works gets all messed up when running inside other functions/environments. Using it interactively like this is what `subset()` was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

First, some example data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Year Total 
2005 238.79
2005 165.46 
2005 196.07 
2005 135.28 
2005 180.30 
2005 237.95 
2008 714.74 
2008 828.19 
2008 516.19 
2009 279.76 
2009 281.88 
2009 338.68", header = TRUE)
```

If you want a normal QQ plot:

```
qqnorm(dat[dat$Year == 2005, "Total"])
```